# ASP.Net MVC Checkboxes Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am an ASP.Net MVC noob.

I cannot get checkboxes to render correctly i.e. checked/unchecked.

This is a snippet of my view:

```
<input id="<%= item.ReportName + "|" + "email" %>" type="checkbox" checked="<% if     (item.Email == true)  { %>true<% } else {  %>false<% } %>" onclick="ajaxfunction(this)" />
```

This is the source view from IE:

```
<input id="TestRep02|showinhomelist" type="checkbox" onclick="ajaxfunction(this)" />
```

Notice that there is no checked attribute in the html source.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
<input id="<%= item.ReportName + "|" + "email" %>" 
    type="checkbox" <% if (item.Email == true)  { %>checked="yes"<% } %>"
    onclick="ajaxfunction(this)" />
```

Note: The checked attributes accepts "yes" and "no".. not true or false..

Comment: wow, thanks for the lightening response!! works as expected now.

Comment: I think checked="checked" is the proper attribute name/value to use.  See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/checked